# Adjusting width of TextAreaFor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that has a few `TextBoxFor` and 1 `TextAreaFor`

Here it is:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ToEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ToEmail)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message,60, 150, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

A picture of what it looks like:

[image]

The problem is that I am unable to adjust the width of the `TextAreaFor`.

I know that Bootstrap grid system is restricting this, but I don't think this should be impossible to simply keep the label where it is, but make the textareafor wider instead of taller.

What I am looking for, is my `TextAreaFor` to be wider than the regular `TextBoxFor`.  I have tried inserting outrageous numbers into the `int rows` && `int columns` parameters of `TextAreaFor` but the only one that seems to work is `int rows`.

Any idea on how I can get my `TextAreaFor` to expand across the page?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I have created this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4d8iRRAOMz) for all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.  After Inspecting the Elements, I saw that all of the `input`, `textarea`, and `select` had a `max-width` of `280px`.

So all I had to do was give the `textarea` a class and set its `max-width` to something that I prefer.